# Trouble renaming in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer

In Windows 8 when using File Explorer to rename either a file or a folder it aborts the process.
By that I mean while typing File Explorer will flash and return to the original name. This occurs whether I start the process from the File Explorer menu or by slow double click on the name. This is particularly annoying when I have added a new folder. Often after 3 or 4 tries it will allow the change.

Can anyone help me eliminate this problem?

Comment: Have you ran DISM to attempt to repair your installation

Comment: Hitting the touchpad while typing?